# What are the client side requirements to enable the "upload multiple files" link?

Tags: wss-3.0, document-library, file-upload

What are the client side requirements to enable the "upload multiple files" link?  I'm using WSS 3.0.  Also using FBA, not sure if that matters.  It "works on my machine", but not for some other users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the requirements for 'upload multiple files'

1. The 32 bit version of Internet Explorer. The 64 bit version does not support it and neither do other, non IE, browsers.
2. The STSUpld.UploadCtl IE add-in must be enabled.
3. Office 2003 or newer on the client
4. Client integration will need to be enabled for the web app.

For details [see this post](http://alstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/04/problem-user-complains-that-upload.html).

Comment: Muhimbi is spot on here. As for the IE version, official support is for 32 bit IE 7, 8 and 9. See the following link for the MS Browser Support documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is actually Office 2010 that provides the drag and drop interface for multiple uploads.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IE11, you need to run the site in Compatibility mode, or the multiple file upload option will be missing.

Comment: IE11 wasn't released yet when this question was asked in June of 2011.

Comment: But today it is, and hence this answer can be very useful

Answer (score 0):

The link in the Actions drop down requires any version of IE.  If you mean the slick drag and drop interface from the upload multiple files link on the upload page, then IE8 or higher, I'm unsure about IE 6 and 7.

Comment: Yes the 'slick' one is what I'm talking about.  I think it needs IE though, since it works on my machine with IE but not Chrome.  I'm on IE9, but I wonder what version is required?

Comment: Looks like it's An IE feature, in 8 or higher, I don't recall if I had it available in 7.  Firefox and Chrome the upload multiple option is not there or doesn't do anything when clicked, so that makes it not dependant on Office (maybe I'm thinking of SPS 2003 on that one).

Comment: edit my response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If a 64Bit edition of office is installed, it also won't work. You need an installed 32bit component of office. This deploys the required [STSUPLD.DLL](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11234.sharepoint-2010-how-to-enable-uploading-multiple-documents-functionality.aspx) to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14`.

Today we solved the issue by installing the 32bit version of SharePoint Designer 2010 side-by-side with a 64bit Office 2016.