# SharePoint 2007 MultipleUpload is not uploading files

Tags: 2007, file-upload

I have an issue when uploading multiple documents. The multiple documents page opens fine, and I am able to select files. When hitting upload, the Status wheel is spinning for about 20 seconds, and then the status is returning Failed. When I use the UlsViewer I cannot find anything relevant, not any exception or anything.

Does anyone know what this could be? Single upload works fine, and everthing else is also working fine.

[Screenshot on skydrive](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=94E3B412BEB8D7B3&id=94E3B412BEB8D7B3!171#cid=94E3B412BEB8D7B3&id=94E3B412BEB8D7B3!1881)

Comment: Have you tried to run [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) while you upload to see the traffic

Comment: Hi Per Jakobsen. No I have not tried to run fiddler. Maybe I will give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the following points before trying to upload multiple documents.

1. All file extensions should be allowed on SharePoint.
2. Verify that the size of the documents does not exceeds the upload limit.

Beyond the above minimum requirements the scope of the issue should not exceed more than whats mentioned in these below links:-

[Multiple File Upload Prerequisites](http://voices.yahoo.com/techtips-upload-multiple-files-option-6787802.html)

[Client Side Prerequisites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14116/what-are-the-client-side-requirements-to-enable-the-upload-multiple-files-link/14121#14121)

[For SharePoint 2010/drag and drop feature](http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2011/08/04/multiple-file-upload-and-drag-and-drop-file-feature-on-sharepoint-2010/)

Let us know if following the above still does not resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi @moss-farmer Sorry for not comming back to you on this. I have been busy, and the notification email from stackexchange has probably never reached me. My issue is not that I am unable to get the Multiple Upload screen to appear. If you take a look at the linked screenshot in my post, the issue is with the upload, and yes, the files is supported format and not exceeding 50mb.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been installing and/or configuring any IIS extensions lately? I've experienced the same thing while using the latest build of the SmoothStreaming Extensions on IIS: I fixed it like this http://forums.iis.net/p/1185944/2009971.aspx

Comment: Hi @c-marius, I have not done anything with IIS.